# How to create a `TypedColumn` of Apache Spark in a type safe way?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset

Is there any technology like [quicklens](https://github.com/adamw/quicklens)?

I was a Scala developers for many years. But I am new in Spark.
I wonder if we can generate a specific `TypedColumn` with the ability of type-checking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that https://github.com/typelevel/frameless provided a `TypedDataset` for using Spark in a type safe way.